# Which Perl session management library works well with TemplateToolkit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, session-management

I've considered [`CGI::Application`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Application) and [`CGI::Session`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Session). Of the two, [`CGI::Session`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Session) seems more promising. [`CGI::Application`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Application) model, however, doesn't look like it would work well with [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/). (Am I wrong to think so?)

I would like to evaluate more session management libraries, before comitting to one. Any recommendations? I'm looking for a library that's web server agnostic, and works across multiple servers. [Catalyst](http://catalystframework.org/) is not an option for now, due to the time required to retrofit existing code into the [Catalyst](http://catalystframework.org/) way of doing things.

Comment: I don't understand you requirement for the session management library to work well with your template library. What exactly is it that you are looking for?

Comment: Some session management libraries are embedded deep inside some large framework such Catalyst which demands that you do things their way. Our own framework uses the TemplateToolkit way of MVC (sort of). Thus, we'll need a library that doesn't require us to use their way of doing things. (In short, a loosely coupled library)

Comment: OK. Got it. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Not sure why you feel the pressure to move to Catalyst, there is nothing wrong with using CGI::Application moving forward.  It is pretty close to the CGI way of doing things, with a nice set of plugins and modules to do 'modern' things.  CGI::Application also has URL based dispatching with CGI::Application::Dispatch and integrates well with CGI::Session through CGI::Application::Plugin::Session (and TT through CGI::Application::Plugin::TT of course).  The learning curve, memory use and startup time of Catalyst are all higher than for cgi-app.

Comment: Pressured, moi? I'm just clarifying. That comment was for @manni only. Anyway, thanks for all your speedy replies. Much appreciated. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`CGI::Application`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Application) and [`CGI::Session`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Session) are very different modules. [`CGI::Session`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Session) is a session module - it does not do anything beyond this. [`CGI::Application`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Application) is a lightweight framework. It works well with [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/), some of us use with [`CGI::Application::Plugin::TT`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Application::Plugin::TT).

So, if you need sessions only, use CGI::Session.

If you need better structure of your code - use CGI::Application. You can even use CGI::Session in it, with CGI::Application::Plugin::Session.

Comment: Good answer. Just what I wanted to know. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Apache::Session](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Apache::Session) with some success. Although the name tells a different story, I don't think it will only work with an Apache webserver.

The nice thing is that you can easily change the way sessions are stored without changing your own session handling code. E.g. you might start out with sessions being stored as files on disk and then move to a DB based system. And then change the DB backend after that.

Comment: I don't see what you gain with Apache::Session over CGI::Session/CGI::Application::Plugin::Session, as the advantages you describe for Apache::Session are available for CGI::Session.

Comment: So this makes Apache::Session bad advice and a reason for a downvote?

Comment: CGI::Session is better developed than Apache::Session. Both has some advantages over another.